# Accessing slice by index when slice is pointer

Tags: go

Is there a short hand for accessing `x.Bar[0]` in the following case?

The direct attempt results in `(type *[]string does not support indexing)` for obvious reasons

```
type A struct {
    B *[]string
}


x := &Foo{Bar: &[]string{"1", "2"}}
```

Comment: What is the reason to have a pointer to a slice? PS: `(*x.Bar)[0]`

Comment: I have abstracted some more complex protobuf stuff :)

Comment: Related / possible duplicate of: [Slicing a slice pointer passed as argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38013922/slicing-a-slice-pointer-passed-as-argument/38014097#38014097).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It would be

```
(*x.Bar)[0]
```

You use parentheses to change the precedence of operators: `[]` has a higher precedence than `*`.