# Map initialization in Go

Tags: dictionary, go, memory, initialization, slice

As far as I understand, types `slice` and `map` are similar in many ways in Go. They both `reference` (or `container`) types. In terms of abstract data types, they represent an array and an associative array, respectively.

However, their behaviour is quite different.

```
var s []int
var m map[int]int
```

While we can use a declared slice immediately (append new items or reslice it), we cannot do anything with a newly declared map. We have to call `make` function and initialize a map explicitly. Therefore, if some struct contains a map we have to write a constructor function for the struct.

So, the question is why it is not possible to add some syntaсtic sugar and both allocate and initialize the memory when declaring a map.

I did google the question, learnt a new word "avtovivification", but still failing to see the reason.

I am not talking about struct literal. Yes, you can explicitly initialize a map by providing values such as `m := map[int]int{1: 1}`. However, if you have some [struct](https://play.golang.org/p/A1GgAndnccD):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type SomeStruct struct {
    someField map[int]int
    someField2 []int
}

func main() {
    s := SomeStruct{}
    s.someField2 = append(s.someField2, -1) // OK
    s.someField[0] = -1 // panic: assignment to entry in nil map
    fmt.Println(s)
}
```

It is not possible to use a struct immediately (with default values for all fields). One has to create a constructor function for `SomeStruct` which has to initialize a map explicitly.

Comment: That "syntactical sugar" is already there but it is not sugar but plain simple Go object literal syntax: {}`. Both--slices and maps--behave exactly the same.

Comment: @Volker as far as understand, they are not behaving the same way. Could you please have a look at the example I added to the question?

Comment: They do behave exactly the same. If you try to assign to any element of a nil slice you get a panic too. What you perceive as a difference in the behavior of nil slices and nil maps is a _special_ _property_ of the append function which allows its first argument to be nil. There is no append for maps but this is not a difference on how nil slices and nil maps behave. If you write your own appendMap function you can treat a nil map special too.

Comment: @Volker, ок, thank you for the clarification. Now I see that they behave exactly the same. Maybe I should reframe the question. Why do they both behave as they behave? You mentioned that a `special property` allows `append` to deal with nil slices. But why instead we do not initialize both map and slice during the declaration? Anyway in 99% of cases we *eventually* will initialize the variable (map or slice). In this case, we do not need any special properties.

Comment: Initializing during declaration is undoable in practice. Take slices. How long would you like your slice be? At declaration time you cannot know so it must be 0. How large should the capacity be? You do not know and any default like 17 will destroy the ability to initialize a slice with the right capacity to avoid reallocation. If you want a constructed non-nil slice or map just add {}.

Comment: @Volker But how this behaviour is different from `m := make(map[int]int)`? As far as I understand, the map is also created with some non-nil default capacity.

Comment: I do not understand your last question. A slice made like `make(map[int]int, 0)` has capacity of zero, just like one made with `[]int{}`. For maps there might or might not be a difference in capacity for `make(map[int]int)` and `map[int]int{}` as this is unspecified by the language spec and any Go version might do something different. I am not sure what actual problem you are trying to understand.

Comment: Questions of language design decisions can only be answered by language designers, not by the community at large.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> While we can use a declared slice immediately (append new items or reslice it), we cannot do anything with a newly declared map. We have to call `make` function and initialize a map explicitly. Therefore, if some struct contains a map we have to write a constructor function for the struct.

That's not true. Default value–or more precisely [zero value](https://golang.org/ref/spec#The_zero_value)–for both slices and maps is `nil`. You may do the "same" with a `nil` map as you can do with a `nil` slice. You can check length of a `nil` map, you can index a `nil` map (result will be the zero value of the value type of the map), e.g. the following are all working:

```
var m map[int]int

fmt.Println(m == nil) // Prints true
fmt.Println(len(m))   // Prints 0
fmt.Println(m[2])     // Prints 0
```

Try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/ff7UiRB3kq1).

What you "feel" more about the zero-value slice is that you may add values to it. This is true, but under the hood a new slice will be allocated using the exact [`make()`](https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#make) builtin function that you'd have to call for a map in order to add entries to it, and you have to (re)assign the returned slice. So a zero-value slice is "no more ready for use" than a zero-value map. [`append()`](https://golang.org/pkg/builtin/#append) just takes care of necessary (re)allocation and copying over. We could have an "equivalent" `addEntry()` function to which you could pass a map value and the key-value pairs, and if the passed map is `nil`, it could allocate a new map value and return it. If you don't call `append()`, you can't add values to a `nil` slice, just as you can't add entries to a `nil` map.

The primary reason that the zero value for slices and maps is `nil` (and not an initialized slice or map) is performance and efficiency. It is very often that a map or slice value (either variable or a struct field) will never get used, or not right away, and so if they would be allocated at declaration, that would be a waste of memory (and some CPU) resources, not to mention it gives more job to the garbage collector. Also if the zero value would be an initialized value, it would often be insufficient (e.g. a 0-size slice cannot hold any elements), and often it would be discarded as you add new elements to it (so the initial allocation would be a complete waste).

Yes, there are cases when you do want to use slices and maps right away, in which cases you may call `make()` yourself, or use a [composite literal](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Composite_literals). You may also use the special form of `make()` where you supply the (initial) capacity for maps, avoiding future restructuring of the map internals (which usually requires non-negligible computation). An automatic non-`nil` default value could not guess what capacity you'd require.

Comment: as always thank you for the great answer. Maybe I wrong, but I thought that when you declare variable `var m map[int]int`, the memory is already allocated, but not initialized?

Comment: @AyZu Map values internally are pointers (see [slice vs map to be used in parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47590444/slice-vs-map-to-be-used-in-parameter/47590531#47590531)). A map declaration claims memory for just a pointer (which will point to nowhere), but nothing more will be allocated, not until `make()` is called or a composite literal is used.

Answer (score 3):

You can! What you're looking for is:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    v := map[int]int{}

    v[1] = 1
    v[2] = 2

    fmt.Println(v)
}
```

`:=` is declare *and* assign, where as `var` is simply declare.