# Why can arrays not be used _directly_ when calling a variadic function in Go?

Tags: arrays, go, slice, variadic-functions

What is the reason that, given a *(variadic)* function

```golang
func varargs(n ...int) {}
```

it can be called like

```golang
varargs(1, 2, 3, 4) // Fixed number of arguments
```

but not with an *array*:

```golang
a := [4]int{1, 2, 3, 4} // Fixed number of elements
varargs(a...) // Error: cannot use (type [4]int) as type []int in argument
```

---

I understand why

```golang
var s []int = a
```

wouldn't work: it prevents accidental misuse, requiring manual slicing:

```golang
s := a[:]
```

But why does this restriction extend to calls to variadic functions?

---

***Bonus question:***
Conversely, why would calling

```golang
func fourargs(w, x, y, z int) {}
```

with a *4-element array* like

```golang
fourargs(a...) // Error: not enough arguments in call  have ([4]int...)  
               //                                      want (int, int, int, int)
```

also be forbidden?
It can be type-checked at compile time.

Comment: You are right. There is actually an array among a forest of slices.

Comment: It's not an unreasonable question to ask, and is well-framed;  The downvoters here are just plain mean.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Spec: Passing arguments to ... parameters:](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Passing_arguments_to_..._parameters)

> **If the final argument is assignable to a slice type `[]T`**, it may be passed unchanged as the value for a `...T` parameter if the argument is followed by `...`. In this case no new slice is created.

So when you have a slice and you pass it as the value of the variadic parameter, no new slice is created, it is just assigned.

If you have an array, that is a different type, that is not assignable to a slice type. Therefore it is not allowed.

You must first slice the array, which you can do without an intermediate variable:

```
a := [4]int{1, 2, 3, 4}
varargs(a[:]...)
```

Yes, you could say this automatic slicing could happen automatically / internally. Why this isn't allowed is opinion based (and belongs to the authors of Go). Basically, in Go arrays are secondary. Slices are the way to go. You should have a slice in the first place, which you can pass and you don't have a problem. See related questions: [Why have arrays in Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38645175/why-have-arrays-in-go/38645895#38645895) and [Slicing a slice pointer passed as argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38013922/slicing-a-slice-pointer-passed-as-argument/38014097#38014097).

Comment: I find the "no hidden performance cost" argument (no new slice created) convincing, actually.

Comment: @ᆼᆺᆼActually creating a slice is not much overhead, it's just a tiny header (see [How to inspect slice header?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54195834/how-to-inspect-slice-header/54196005#54196005)), when you pass a "ready" slice that also requires copying the slice header.

Comment: Perhaps there is an overarching "no implicit conversions" philosophy then?

Comment: @ᆼᆺᆼNot sure what you mean. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: I mean Go prefers explicit conversions (eg. no mixing of `int` & `float`), so maybe not automatically slicing an array is in keeping with the same philosophy (I see how this is opinion based).

Comment: @ᆼᆺᆼ`int` to `float` can be achieved with a type conversion. Array to slice is not a conversion, it's a slicing operation. They are not the same.